# What is the name of those transparent soft plastic cases around a potentiometer's hull?

Tags: identification, components, potentiometer

I can't find the name of those transparent soft plastic cases that one can put around a potentiometer's hull to protect them from short-circuits. Anyone?

[image]

Comment: Like this..? https://www.amplifiedparts.com/products/dust-cover-rubber-covering-potentiometers-black

Comment: I think those are for keeping dust out, not for isolation, but I may be wrong. The ones I have seen were known simply as "dust covers".

Comment: Dust cover sounds about right; I've also seen "boot" e.g. https://m-cal.com/en-gb/846280645-mc07-3222d932-raychem-rotary-potentiometer-heat-shrink-boot-19mm

Comment: A plastic cover for the back of a switch, connector or pot is often known as a 'boot'.

Comment: They are dust covers, and they're pretty much worthless.   The bottom where the pins poke out is still wide open.  I do alot of guitar amp work, these Alpha pots are super common with Asian equipment.   I pull the covers off and throw them away.   I doubt you can buy them separate, they come with the new pots when you buy them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments they may be called:

- dust covers
- pot dust seals
- protector caps
- boot